# Metrics for the similarity of two sets of data

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions, approximation

I am trying to model a certain (discrete) behavior measured from source A, and the literature in the field have a model for a source A'.

The behavior itself for sources A and A' are pretty similar in the shape, but not in the absolute value.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3INAZ.png)

In this figure, the plot in blue (G1) is the behavior measured for source A, in green (G2) the simulated behavior using our model for source A; and in red (G3) the simulated value for source A'.

My objective is to show that the *shape* of our model have is a better approximation for this behavior than the previous model. 
(It is quite clear to human eyes but I'd like to have some metric to validate our claim). Problems are:

- The measures of behavior for source A' are unavailable
- An histogram using *Mean Square Error* or even *Mean Absolute Error* in relation to the measures to A is not a fair metric, since the sources are different

At moment, I am using a scatterplot of *Model x Measure*, disregarding the slope and just taking in consideration the Pearson correlation, since models in both cases should grow/decrease at the similar points. Therefore, I am arguing that the greater the correlation, greater is the similarity between the model and the measure.

However, this is kinda indirect measure. Is there a more direct way to do this comparison?

Any help or comment is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The metric you choose should be based on the goals of your task but an overall excellent one for this general task is the mutual information:

$$I(X,Y) = \sum\limits_{y\in Y} \sum\limits_{x \in X} p(x,y) \log \left( {p(x,y) \over p(x) p(y)} \right) ,$$

and measured in *bits* (or *nats*).

This measures how much information about $Y$ is provided by $X$.  If $Y = X$, then if you know $X$ you get no new information about $Y$ by measuring $Y$... you already have it already in $X$.  If, however, $X$ and $Y$ differ significantly, once you know $X$, you get a *lot* of information by then measuring $Y$.